# SSRS - Freezing columns headers and rows - but row group header disappears

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report where I need to freeze the first few rows and headers so they remain visible whilst scrolling. I have done this setting the static member property through advanced mode. So the Row Group Headers remained visible:

[image]

I then fixed the column groups 'Store' and 'Cashier' to remain visible. However, if you scroll down AND across, these headers now disappear:

[image]

In the example, you can no longer see the Headings `Store` or `Cashier`. How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore - seems this only happens in the Report Viewer and not in the application.